# SwipeRefreshLayout with CardView issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview, swiperefreshlayout

I have created view where I have SwipeRefresh. I also have two buttons at the bottom so they can move with soft keyboard up when edittext is tapped. The problem is when textbox is tapped buttons are going top but cardview has higher z-index I think and they are not fully visible

There is a structure:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/refresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px">
       
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">
                 <!-- textboxes and others  components here -->
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:paddingTop="2px">
                <Button
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonAccent"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/startBtn"
                    android:text="START" />
                <Button
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonPrimaryLight"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:id="@+id/continueBtn"
                    android:text="CONTINUE WORK" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Should I manually set z index of the button for higher or there is a better option to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Why minus this question?

Comment: set buttons below the card view

Comment: there are below

Comment: have you added this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
at manifest in Activity tag

Answer (score 0):

If its **above version 21** then your, give your **linear layout** containing buttons **elevation same as card view**.
Because as **card view has z axis**, it takes height and the linear layout doesn't have the height.
But if you are working on **lower than 21 version** then you can keep your **linear layout inside a card view** and give it same elevation as  one above it.

---

I hope it works fine for you.........

---